# Error: Void -> Int should be Float For function argument 'num'

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel, haxelib

Trying to fix this error as I mentioned in title but cant figure it out. I am not comparing anything why I get this I don't know. I tried to change strings to float but no success. Maybe I should change StringTools but not sure what use instead of that.

```
package com.bykd.output;


@:final class DateOutput
{

    public static inline var HOUR : String = "%h";

    public static inline var MONTH : String = "%m";

    public static inline var SECOND : String = "%s"; 

    public static inline var MINUTE : String = "%i";

    public static inline var DAY : String = "%d";

    public static inline var YEAR : String = "%y";


    public function new()
    {
        //super();
    }

    public static function formatDate(date : Date, format : String) : String
    {
        var output : String = null;
        output = format;
        output = StringTools.replace(output, DAY, leadZero(date.getDay));
        output = StringTools.replace(output, MONTH, leadZero(date.getMonth));
        output = StringTools.replace(output, YEAR, date.getFullYear);
        return output;
    }

    public static function formatTime(date : Date, format : String) : String 
    {
        var output : String = null;
        output = format;
        output = StringTools.replace(output, HOUR, leadZero(date.getHours));
        output = StringTools.replace(output, MINUTE, leadZero(date.getMinutes));
        output = StringTools.replace(output, SECOND, leadZero(date.getSeconds));
        return output;
    }

    public static function leadZero(num : Float) : String
    {
        return Std.string("00" + num).substr(-2, 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not _calling_ the functions, you're passing references of them to `leadZero` (hence the error containing a function type). It should be `date.getDay()` etc, not `date.getDay`.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I missed that point unfortunately. Fixed the issue with your help.